# How do I specify line-height in percentages, as I would specify height?

Tags: html, centering, css

For example, I can write this:

```
<div id="foo">Hello</div>
```

And this:

```
#foo {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And it would make the `#foo` element be a block-level element, and have a height of 100px, and centre the word `Hello` inside the div.

But what if I were to write it like this:

```
<div id="foo">Hello</div>
```

And this:

```
#foo {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then all of a sudden, the `line-height` stops working, as the CSS processor assumes the `line-height: 100%` to be normal line height, and not actually the height of the element's parent.

So how would I use percentages with `line-height` as I would with `height`?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe line-height only works with px, em and pt. You might be able to write a script using the element height to get a percentage to then transfer over to the element's line-height.  Do you want it to just be middle aligned?  If so, check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: What effect exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

That's [how the property is supposed to work](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height). When you specify a percentage `line-height`, the resulting pixel value is the element's computed font size times the value you have specified. Setting it to `100%` is the same as setting it to `1`; the parent does not come into it here.

Setting `line-height: inherit` would set the pixel value to whatever the `line-height` of the parent element is, and that might work for you. However, the line height of the (text of the) parent is not necessarily the same as the parent's height in box model terms.